# Can we move/copy a customized list forms (using power app) from one tenant to another

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, export, import, powerapp

I have a communication SharePoint online site collection inside tenantA, the site collection has 3 power-apps which were used to customize its list forms. now i used those 2 commands to re-create the site inside tenantB `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate` & `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate`, but this process will not move the customized forms. so my question is, if there a a way to move/copy the customized list forms (using power app) from one tenant to another ?

Comment: I have tried these steps and did not work for me. MSFT says that it is actually working on this feature. Here is the user voice for the same. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Move-or-Copy-a-SharePoint-list-PowerApps-Custom-Form/idi-p/102744/page/9#comments

Comment: For the list form, you need to perform some other steps as well apart from just export/import.
Refer below article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-power-app-list-form-from-one-tenant-to-another-tenant/

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate SharePoint lists along with the associated Power App-customized forms using [Flows and Power Apps Migrator](https://github.com/Zerg00s/FlowPowerAppsMigrator).

Download the latest release and run the Migrate-Packages.bat batch file. Then follow the instructions on the screen. You can even migrate multiple lists at the same time.

Full disclosure: I wrote this tool, but it's completely free. It used PowerShell PnP under the hood to connect to SharePoint Online sites.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, we can do this using the export and import of the powerapps package. We need to follow the below steps to do that:

1. Export the app from the source environment
2. Import the app into the target environment

**Export Process**

**Step 1:**

Open the PowerApps form in the browser. Go to the Apps tab. Right-click on the Application which you want to move. You will get the context menu Click on the “**Export-Package**“.

**Step 2:**

In the Export package page enter the Name and Description and click on Export.

**Step 3:**

Now we will get our PowerApps form in our local system.

**Import Process:**

**Step 1:**

Open the new tenant in the browser. Go the Apps tab. Click on the “**Import-Package**” from the top.

**Step 2:**

Click on the “Upload” in the Import-Package.

**Step 3:**

Select on the Zip file from the local system which you want to import.

**Step 4:**

Click on the Update. In the Setup option click on the “Create as new” option.

**Step 5:**

Click on save. When we have clicked on the Create as new the save button will be enabled.

**Step 6:**

Click on the Import in the Review Package Content Page.

**Step 7:**

We will get our imported App in the Apps tab.

For complete details steps, you may refer the below MSDN article:

[Environment and tenant app migration through Packaging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/environment-and-tenant-migration)

[Export PowerApps from one Tenant to another Tenant](https://www.sharepointsky.com/export-powerapps-from-one-tenant-to-another-tenant/)

Note:

After importing the package in the target environment, open the form verify the data connection.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that will work for PowerApps customised SharePoint list forms...

I think it only works for PowerApps native apps.

Comment: This won't work for SharePoint forms.

Comment: These steps will work only on MS Flow Power automate but not for the asked question